# Forward UDP packets from one port to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to listen for data on one port and redirect (resend) incoming data to another port on same local machine.

For example I want to listen for data coming on port `60000` and redirect it to `60001`, in this case, send "Hello, World!". To make it super simple, I send data myself when server starts to listen. To do so, I have written simple snipper:

```
const dgram = require("dgram")
const server = dgram.createSocket("udp4")
server.on("listening", () => {
  const buf = Buffer.from("Hello, World!")
  server.send(buf, 0, buf.length, 60001)
})
server.bind(60000, "0.0.0.0")
```

But when I inspect incoming data on wireshark (headless wireshark command: `tshark -f "port 60001"`) I see no incoming packets.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server.send` without an address will send to loopback (127.0.0.1), so make sure wireshark is monitoring this device: `tshark -i loopback -f "port 60001"`.

Comment: Oh, you are actually correct. I had to specify, that I want to listen to loopback also! If you modify your answer, I'll accept it, since I'm on right track now.